# Simplifying matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am self-learning linear algebra and my textbook asks to simplify the following matrix product with no explanation.

$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & -\cos\theta \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta\\
\sin\theta\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Basically I know how to calculate the product of the matrix, etc but what I don't get is how to achieve the answer they have given which is as follows.

$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

What is it that I am missing, or is the answer in the book wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's correct. You just need to multiply it out. You will need to apply the trigonometric formula $\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta =1.$

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong. I was squaring theta instead of the result. Thanks. Will accept your answer once the time has passed :)

Comment: Yeah, I checked it on my graphing calculator just after I posted. Thanks! :D